# How to find Monday with given time?

Tags: javascript, date

I am trying to find the monday for whatever day I am given.
It has two requirements.

For example:

```
1. If given day is Monday through Friday, find the last closest Monday, 
   so if the given day is 10-31, I need to get 10-27
2. If given day is Saturday or Sunday, find the next Monday.
```

JavaScript:

```
var today = new Date(); //assuming it's 11/1/2014 Saturday
var todayDay = today.getDay(); > 6


if(todayDay == 6) {
    var Monday = today.getDate() + 2;
}
```

I am not sure how to find Monday's day and time dynamically. I have looked up the javascript day method but not sure how to get it. Can anyone help me about it? Thanks!

Comment: Your question is not that clear, at least for me. Are you asking how to find the nearest "Monday" in the future to a give date?

Comment: @Antuan please see updates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

javscript's Date object has the methods [getDay()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDay), [setDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate), and [getDate()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getDate) which are helpful for this.

```js
"use strict";

var d = document.getElementById('d');
var mon = document.getElementById('mon');

var handleDatePick = function(ev){
  var the_date = new Date(d.value);
  if (the_date.getDay() <= 4) {
      the_date.setDate( the_date.getDate() - the_date.getDay() );
  } else {
    the_date.setDate( the_date.getDate() + 7 - the_date.getDay() );
  }
  var output = 'the nearest monday is ' + the_date.toUTCString();
  mon.value = output;
};

d.addEventListener('input',handleDatePick);
```

```css
input, output {
  display: block;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
pick the date: <input type="date" id="d" />

<output id="mon" for="d"></output>
```

Answer (score 2):

so to rephrase your requirement is : given week starts on sunday, find monday in that week.

using moment.js its far too easy...

this week's Sunday

```
moment().startOf('week')
```

so to find Monday do

```
moment().startOf('week').add('days', 1)
```

**EDIT**

you can change the start of week using below moment function

```
moment.lang('en-in', {
    week : {
        dow : 1 // Monday is the first day of the week
    }
});
```

and days of the week array to get index is

```
   daysOfWeek: ['Su', 'Mo', 'Tu', 'We', 'Th', 'Fr', 'Sa'],
```